# Can i push the "back" button in chrome with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like help to understand how I can go to the previous page in chrome if i try to join m.facebook.com

Let me show you my code until now:

```
var host = "http://www.google.com";          // here you put the URL that you want to be redirected 



chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
         return {redirectUrl: host + details.url.match(/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+([\S\s]*)/)[1]};              //where it says "host" you put the name of the var that you have set above to the URL that you want to be redirected


    },
    {
        urls: [
            "*://m.facebook.com/*"                  // here you put the URL that you want to block.
        ],
        types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

manifest

```
{
    "name": "Facebook Notification Block",
    "description": "Block Notification",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
            "webRequest",
            "*://facebook.com/*",
            "*://m.facebook.com/*",
            "*://www.facebook.com/*",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ]
}
```

With this code I can "block" m.facebook.com and redirect to "www.google.com" from my Chrome browser when i have installed the extension. But i want just to go to the previous page.

UPDATE1:

Like christopher suggested i tried these codes

added to the manifest permissions "history"

and i made the background.js like this

```
var goBack = function() {
    window.history.back();
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
         return {goBack};               


    },
    {
        urls: [
            "*://m.facebook.com/*"                  // here you put the URL that you want to block.
        ],
        types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

But i cant figure out my mistake.

Comment: look at what you are returning in onBeforeRequest. you need to know more javascript to program this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Answer (score 2):

```
var goBack = function() {
    window.history.back();
}
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: @ZigMandel however i tried i cant manage to make it work. im gonna post the updated codes

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chrome.history API extension to read the history, from there I guess you can get the previous page.

[history extension source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history)